# Mac OS X Message app cannot be opened after TRYING to install windows 10 with BootCamp

Tags: macos, boot-camp, ichat

So I've tried to install windows 10 using BootCamp but somehow Windows installer didn't allow my to choose partition, I've tried to format new one inside the installer but still no lock...

so I've decided to cancel installation, everything went smoothly but Message app give me this error:

```
Messages cannot be opened because of a problem.

Check with the developer to make sure Messaes works with this version o OS X. You may need to reinstall the application...
```

How to reinstall this?

```
Process:               Messages [2130]
Path:                  /Applications/Messages.app/Contents/MacOS/Messages
Identifier:            com.apple.iChat
Version:               ???
Build Info:            iChat-4760000000000000~1
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Messages [2130]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-08-19 11:39:27.836 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        E380EDE0-7C60-4B77-F46A-B109930377E5

Sleep/Wake UUID:       F5E57671-7C1A-4968-8F60-904EF0F39BB7

Time Awake Since Boot: 28000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2700 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _kAccountSendUnencryptedFilesKey
  Referenced from: /Applications/Messages.app/Contents/MacOS/Messages
  Expected in: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SocialAppsCore.framework/Versions/A/SocialAppsCore
 in /Applications/Messages.app/Contents/MacOS/Messages
```

Comment: The big mistake was to let Windows itself touch the drive. It simply doesn't understand how it's faked in to thinking it's in charge. Boot to Recovery & verify/repair the disk, fix perms while you're there. Were you at least using Boot Camp 6?

Comment: I'll try that. Yep, I've red that newest Boot Camp got some updates for Windows 10. Will let you know if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck ;(

Comment: Then I'd start with the 'first fix' toolkit. Disk Utility, fix permissions, check & if necessary repair disk. Then get the combo updater for your current OS [10.10.5 here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832) & re-apply it.

Comment: I'll throw that into an Answer then. Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with the 'first fix' toolkit...

- Disk Utility, Repair Permissions, Verify & if necessary Repair Disk.
- Then get the Combo Updater for your current OS - [combo updater for OS X 10.10.5 here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832) & re-apply it.